# Incorrect registry entry created by REG ADD "path\nodeName"

Tags: c#, cmd, regedit

I need to create a new node value which I will add data entries to.
On the surface it all works, but using windiff it looks like this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:448]
@=""
"SslCertHash"=hex:fd,5b,72,a5,aa,12,0f,2b,73,95,c4,10,63,49,bd,7d,ca,ce,99,e4
```

When it should look like this (no @ thing):

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo\0.0.0.0:448]
"SslCertHash"=hex:fd,5b,72,a5,aa,12,0f,2b,73,95,c4,10,63,49,bd,7d,ca,ce,99,e4
```

Note: The above result is after the data entries have been added which is why the SslCertHash stuff is there.
I am using this exact command via a C# process:

```
cmd.exe /c REG ADD "path\nodeName"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node with the name @ is the default node. It should be no problem that it is there alongside your own node "SslCertHash".

Comment: Why is it on some nodes and not on others?
Also: I want to test IF its the problem, the "how" of which remains unanswered. But ty anyway.

Comment: I tested by deleting the node after the IIS set it up correctly and running my own scripts again. It worked which means the IIS setup does something else unrelated to the registry.